# Is it possible make XSS attacks to a react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have issues with escape values in my app. So I found this documentation to fix it:https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

But it says it prevents XSS attacks. Is it possible to make an XSS attack or similar to a react native app? Maybe through deep links etc.?
I'm not using web views. So it's not a concern.

```
const title = t('activities:title', {
fullname: user.fullName,
interpolation: { escapeValue: false }, });
```

I fetch fullname from the backend and I have a deep link logic here but I just pass user-id on deep links, not fullname or other things.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible and this setting is for vanilla js or similar things. As react.i18n documentation React already prevents XSS attacks and it's not necessary to use this option.

https://react.i18next.com/getting-started